# Node.js | Запрос по http.request выкидывает в ошибку - ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js

Стоит мне задействовать метод request объекта http то я сразу вижу ошибку в консоли

`node:events:304 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^`

Или она же целиком:

```
node:events:304
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1129:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:129:14)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:478:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:327:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:194:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:159:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080
}

Process finished with exit code 1
```

http.request просто НЕ работает с различными примерами он падает в эту ошибку каждый раз! Что это за ерунда? Допустим, пример из книги:

```
const http = require('http');

const options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: '8080',
    path: '/hello.html'
};

function getResponse(response) {
    let data = '';
    response.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', () => console.log(data));
}

http.request(options, response => {
    getResponse(response);
}).end();
```

Улетает туда же. Как и все остальные. Работает все остальное но не http.request. Почему он постоянно крашится?

win 10, noda последняя, порты менять пробовал

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что это единственная строчка в выводе ошибки?

Comment: Нет, обновил и добавил полный вывод

Comment: А сервер на localhost:8080 у вас присутствует? Рекомендую для начала добиться нормального ответа от него без nodejs, из браузера или каким-нибудь curl

Comment: Если node.js внутри виртуальной машины/контейнера - нужно заменить localhost на другой IP, потому что localhost - это loopback внутрь контейнера

Comment: мне нужно сначала создать сервер на этом порте? То есть http.createServer и листен 8800 соответственно? Это логично я в конечном итоге так и сделал. Не буду говорить о том что все прекрасно заработало, но по крайней мере и не упало. Смутил сам пример, если это на самом деле должно быть так (да?) то почему в примерах то сервер развернут не был? Странно

Comment: Пример http запроса. Предполагается, что если вам нужен http запрос, то вы в курсе для чего он вам нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну а сервер то кто будет поднимать вася